# Should deleted questions still show up in a Google search?

Tags: discussion, bug, seo

*Perhaps this question needs to be on “[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)” but posting it here for now…*

---

So I was doing a Google search for “[Turning Logstash data into relational data](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=Turning%20Logstash%20data%20into%20relational%20data&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)” and saw the following results. See screenshot below and note the 5th result at the bottom of the following screenshot is a Stack Overflow post titled “[Handling relational data in Logstash.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454442/handling-relational-data-in-logstash)”

But also note that the post is deleted:

> deleted by Community♦ Apr 21 at 4:08 (RemoveAbandonedQuestions)

The question is why is this post still coming up in Google searches? Assuming that April 21s is this year, it’s nearly 3 weeks since it was deleted. Shouldn’t Google have removed it from their search cache by now?

I mean it’s not just deleted, but it’s technically a year old, no votes up or down and no answers so it seems like it should not warrant being ranked in a search on Google at all… Let alone in this dead/deleted state.

FWIW: I have been doing web dev and admin long enough to know that each service indexing is not an exact science. But it still feels weird that a site as large, well respected and quickly indexed as the Stack Exchange sites would run into a “zombie” result post like this.

[image: Screenshot of Google results page here.]

[image: Screenshot of deleted post here.]

Comment: You never know. I've seen results for pages that have been gone for at least a few months.

Comment: Depends a bit how often the Google BOT hits that url. I don't think the sitemap.xml https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22308/stack-overflow-sitemap-wtf  includes urls for recent deleted posts but a dev needs to confirm.

Comment: Maybe google is so smart it knows you have 10k+ rep and CAN see the deleted post.

Comment: We have no real control over what Google tries to remember.  Or for that matter other web sites that have a link to the deleted question, thus encouraging Google to push it up.  Only practical concern is "don't break the internet", applies when really old questions get deleted.

Comment: @rene Our sitemap has for anlong time not included URLs to everything. It is basically a long list of recently updated posts so Google can update pages that have changed and crawl new pages. These kinds of questions that sat around for a year with no attention and then got silently deleted haven't been in the list for a very long time, so it would probably take some time for Google to want to look at it again and remove it from results.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From animuson, [in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367881/should-deleted-questions-still-show-up-in-a-google-search#comment589298_367881):

> Our sitemap has for [a long] time not included URLs to everything. It is basically a long list of recently updated posts so Google can update pages that have changed and crawl new pages. These kinds of questions that sat around for a year with no attention and then got silently deleted haven't been in the list for a very long time, so it would probably take some time for Google to want to look at it again and remove it from results.

Comment: @OurManinBananas: Because it's just a quote from someone else, so it's courteous not to get any rep from it. Personally I find it sad that we can't even trust staff members to rightly comprehend the Q&A model and post answers as answers, but there we go.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  `:%s/rep/tag points in both discussion and bug`

Comment: sorry yes, realized that right after I posted, need to try *engage eyes > engage brain > branch Yes or No *